# .htaccess instructions conflict "DocumentRoot change" + "always display subdomain"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite that changes my DocumentRoot from `/public_html` to `/public_html/MAIN` and it works great.

```
RewriteRule ^$ /MAIN/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/MAIN/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /MAIN/$1
```

Now If I try to add the following instruction to always show the `www` subdomain, it no longer behaves properly...

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Visiting `http://domain.com/` causes a rewrite to `http://www.domain.com/MAIN/` which is not what I want. *I do not want the `MAIN` subdirectory to be visible.*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^(.*)$` pattern captures the current URI, no matter it's in the location bar or it's an internal redirection. One of these solutions should work:

- Put the subdomain redirection first
- Replace `$1` with a variable, e.g. `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Thank you @Álvaro substituting `$1` with `%{REQUEST_URI}` did the trick!