# Help with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some issues trying to set up the .htaccess to have the [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) URLs the way I want.

I want to redirect URLs like so:

- **domain.com/fr/store** loads from
  **domain.com/store?__store=france**
- **domain.com/fr/store/category.html**
  loads from
  **domain.com/store/category.html?__store=france**
- **domain.com/fr/store/category/product.html**
  loads from
  **domain.com/store/category/product.html?__store=france**

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^fr/store(.*)$ /store/$1?___store=france [L,P]
```

It works to redirect everything to the main store, but I can't access sub-directories or pages.

Answer (score 0):

The `^(.*)$` pattern captures the current URI, no matter it's in the location bar or it's an internal redirection. One of these solutions should work:

- Put the subdomain redirection first
- Replace `$1` with a variable, e.g. `%{REQUEST_URI}`

*This answer was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451661/htaccess-instructions-conflict-documentroot-change-always-display-subdomain/4451897#4451897); it was originally written by user Álvaro G. Vicario.*